# Error message "No parameterless constructor defined for this object"

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

```
var plugins = Activator.CreateInstance(types.First()) as IPluginFinder;
```

This code stops with error in nopcommerce 4.10, These are that, In the previous version had no problem (4.00)

Full code:

```
var types = typeFinder.FindClassesOfType<IPluginFinder>();

if (types.Count() == 1)
{
    var plugins = Activator.CreateInstance(types.First()) as IPluginFinder;
    var currentPlugin = plugins.GetPluginDescriptorBySystemName("misc.myplugin");
    if (currentPlugin == null || currentPlugin.Installed == false)
        return;
}
```

> Error:
>   No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Answer (score 3):

With version 4.10 the `PluginFinder` class got a new constructor which needs a parameter of type `IEventPublisher` (see [github commit](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/commit/e18a2f97e97bb6c63fd514875e7d196ab8088c7f#diff-397fe785a676ee8d5a603c07f3516a0dR24)). You will need to provide a value for that parameter. I don't know this product, but maybe you'll find something about that in the release notes or the docs.

```
IEventPublisher evtPub = ...; //
var plugins = Activator.CreateInstance(types.First(), evtPub) as IPluginFinder;
```